# Login Authentication using self hosted API (WPF)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm developing a system with my classmate, he created a self-hosted API using WPF, while I'm on the mobile part. I already get the data using GetAsync and Post data using Post Async, What I want now is Login Authentication to our system.

[Here is the Web API I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQ5O.png)

What I want is to use this as my API for authentication, But whenever I search for this topic, all of the results are Azure, WCF, ASP.Net.

I know that my friend uses ASP nugget to create API while searching so far on this topic. Theirs always using those 3 and the codes for validation is in the ASP, WCF or Azure.

I also don't get the concept of a token and I guess I don't need it on the self-hosted API.

This is the best example of what I'm talking about:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-one/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-two/

These two set of tutorials are very helpful, but I'm not aiming for this thing. I just want a simple authentication using the API on the picture.

It's just a simple school work, I'm the beginner in mobile development and c#.

Thanks in advance for viewing my POST :)

Answer (score 1):

While your question is waaaaaay to broad for a single answer on Stack Overflow, here are some pointers for you. Don't overthink things and keep it simple.

I think the easiest way to tackle your problem is to issue a token for your mobile app. This can be any type of token if you don't really care about security.

So in your app, you present the user with a username/password dialog. Pressing a login button:

1. you hit your API sending that username and password
2. API checks whether username and password is in database or a valid combination
3. generates a token if OK and sends as response and saves that token in database
4. then when hitting other urls in your API from mobile app, you need to provide the token as header or query string parameter

This is probably the simplest form of authentication you can do.